# Fibonacci trees with weights

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I'm trying to draw Fibonacci trees, but to make them look more like a real life tree I'm drawing them backwards with the following conditions:

- The n-th Fibonacci tree (Ft) should have F_n leaves (final nodes)
- The n-th Ft has as the left branch to the (n-1)-th Ft and as the right branch to the (n-2)-th Ft.
- Every branch has a weight. If goes to the left it will have weight, say, 1 and if goes to the right has weight 2.
- The difference in weights are represented in the drawing by different lengths for branches
- All the "short" branches should have the same length and the same for the "long" branches.

(see code and picture below)

Right now I'm doing it manually and I'm sure in the worst possible way, as can be seen in my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
This is $Ft_3$:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw (0,2) -- +(-1,1);% short
\draw (0,2) -- +(1.4,1.4);% long
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\hfil%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
This is $Ft_4$:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[red] (0,2) -- +(-1,1);% <- left is shorter
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- +(1.4,1.4);% <- right is longer
\draw[red] (-1,3) -- +(-1,1);% <- left is shorter
\draw[blue] (-1,3) -- +(1.4,1.4);% <- right is longer
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

This is $Ft_5$, the left part is (a modification of) {\color{red}$Ft_4$} and the right part is (a modification of) {\color{blue}$Ft_3$}:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2); %root
\draw[red] (0,2) -- +(-1.5,1);% short
\draw[red] (-1.5,3) -- +(-0.5,1.5);% short
\draw[red] (-1.5,3) -- +(1,2.5);% long
\draw[red] (-2,4.5) -- +(-.8,.8);% short
\draw[red] (-2,4.5) -- +(.8,.8);% short
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- +(2,1.5);% long
\draw[blue] (2,3.5) -- +(-.8,.8);% short
\draw[blue] (2,3.5) -- +(.8,2);% long
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The root has been enlarged to make it look "better". As it can be seen, the drawings cannot be completely simétrica to avoid the overlapping of branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
This is $Ft_3$:
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    minimum width = 4em,
            delay = {where content={}{shape=coordinate}{},
% tree
    calign=fixed edge angles,
    calign angle=45,
    grow=north,
          },
      }
% tree body
[
    [
        [ ]
        [
            []
            []
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, I didn't add weights (it can be done easy) since I lost in your description. I will add them if you will provide a sketch with tree, containing weights.

**Addendum:**
The MWE for the last tree in your question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
This is $Ft_5$, the left part is (a modification of) \textcolor{red}{$Ft_4$} and the right part is (a modification of) \textcolor{blue}{$Ft_3$}:

\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {calign=fixed edge angles,
            if level = 1{calign angle=60}%
                        {calign angle=30},
          grow'=north,
          },
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
%
[
    [
        [, for tree={edge={red}}
            [
                [,tier=L3]
                [,tier=L3]
            ]
            [,tier=L3]
        ]
        [, for tree={edge={blue}}
            [,tier=L3]
            []
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, I liked the syntax of `forest` package. I have edited my question in the hope that it will be clearer